# API to modify document content, ala App Script Document.*?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

Are there any plans to open this extremely useful API to tools outside of App Script?

We love App Script, but need this access from other systems.

Comment: I don't mind the downvotes, but please explain why you're downvoting. Google is pointing people here in lieu of using the Google forum, hence the question.  How is this not an appropriate question?

Answer (score 0):

Not yet but this is something we are actively looking into. In the mean time unfortunately you are stuck with Apps Script or you can upload a file format that we can convert to a Google Document for instance an ODTor an RTF file and upload them to Drive via the API with the `convert` URL parameter to `true`. See: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#convert